# Referencing a theorem by name only

Tags: theoremname

I was wondering if I can have a named theorem (without number) and still call it by the name is printing. The following is the code in the preamble so that I can give a name to the theorem. (I obtained this code from another post).

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newcommand{\thistheoremname}{}
\newtheorem{genericthm}[thm]{\thistheoremname}
\newenvironment{namedthm}[1]
  {\renewcommand{\thistheoremname}{#1}%
   \begin{genericthm}}
  {\end{genericthm}}

\newtheorem*{genericthm*}{\thistheoremname}
\newenvironment{namedthm*}[1]
  {\renewcommand{\thistheoremname}{#1}%
   \begin{genericthm*}}
  {\end{genericthm*}}
```

The following is the what I want the theorem to say. Note I use namedthm* so that no number appears.

```
\begin{namedthm*}{Theorem A}\label{theoremA} Some text.
\end{namedthm*}
```

When I use Theorem \ref{theoremA}, it doesn't print Theorem A. Is there any way I can get that to print?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dummy counter and make its representation to be `\thistheoremname`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem*{genericthm*}{\thistheoremname}
\newcommand{\thistheoremname}{???}% initialize
\newcounter{genericthm}
\renewcommand{\thegenericthm}{\thistheoremname}
\newenvironment{namedthm*}[1]
  {\renewcommand{\thistheoremname}{#1}%
   \refstepcounter{genericthm}%
   \begin{genericthm*}}
  {\end{genericthm*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{namedthm*}{Theorem A}\label{theoremA}
Some text.
\end{namedthm*}

\ref{theoremA}

\end{document}
```

Note that `hyperref` is not necessary; I load it in the example just to check compatibility.

[image]

Let's check that the link is indeed correct: the PDF viewer I use shows a reduced image of the text a link points to when hovering it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This was incredibly helpful!

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use the methods of `thmtools` for creating theorem-like environments, then also incorporating `cleveref` and `crossreftools` allows what seems to be an equivalent result.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  bodyfont=\slshape,
]{thmstyle}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  notefont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  notebraces={}{},
  headformat=\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
  bodyfont=\slshape,
]{namedthmstyle}
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem, style=thmstyle]{theorem}

\declaretheorem[
  style=namedthmstyle,
  name=Theorem,
  title = {},
  numberlike=theorem,
]{namedtheorem}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\Crefname{theorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}

\usepackage{crossreftools}
\newcommand{\crefthm}[1]{\hyperlink{\crtrefanchor{#1}}{\crtrefname{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:one}
$1+1 = 2$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{namedtheorem}[Pythagorean theorem]\label{thm:pythagoras}

The square on the hypotenuse of a right triangle equals the sum of the squares on th eother two sides.

\end{namedtheorem}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:two}
$0 < 1$.
\end{theorem}

Consult \cref{thm:one}, \crefthm{thm:pythagoras}, and \cref{thm:two}.

\end{document}
```

[image: Named theorem cross-reference]